# A loop inside of a drawing (Asymptote)

Tags: asymptote

In MetaPost one can use a loop inside a drawing command; for example

`draw for ix=1 upto 8:(ix*2, 1/(1+cosd ix)).. endfor origin;`

I failed to do the same in Asymptote; tried something like

`draw(for (int k=0; k<=10; ++k){(sin(k),cos(k),sin(k/10))..}cycle);`

checked few tutorials, but did not find an answer.

> Hope it is possible, is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asymptote does not allow inline for loops this way. You can imitate them using anonymous functions as in [g.kov's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/494853/484), but it's really clunky.

Here is a more idiomatic alternative:

```
triple[] points;
for (int k=0; k<=10; ++k) {
    points.push((sin(k),cos(k),sin(k/10)));
}
draw(operator..(...points) .. cycle);
```

The function you are using here is called `operator..`. Normally `operator..(a, b, c, d)` is a more clunky way of writing `a..b..c..d`; but if you call it as a function, you can expand an array by putting three dots in front of it, so that

```
pair[] points = {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9};
guide g = operator..(...points);
```

is equivalent to

```
guide g = a1 .. a2 .. a3 .. a4 .. a5 .. a6 .. a7 .. a8 .. a9;
```

If you want to use a `for` loop to produce the `points` list, the `operator..(...points)` notation becomes invaluable.

Comment: +1 this is a nice one.

Comment: Good that both of you took care of this. ;-) +1 to both you and @g.kov.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is such a macro constructor
in the Asymptote (it's not a macro language), 
but instead we can do something equivalent like

```
import graph3;
size(9cm);

guide3 loop(int n, triple F(int,int)){
  guide3 g;
  for (int k=0; k<=n; ++k)g=g..F(k,n);
  return g..cycle;
}

draw(
  loop(
   10, 
   new triple(int k, int n){return (sin(k),cos(k),sin(k/n));} 
  )
 ,red+0.7bp
);
```

This example uses an anonymous function inside the `loop()` 
call from within the `draw()` command,
but there are more options available, for example,
define function(s) to be used explicitly, 
or define a special `draw()` command, 
create a class that will generate and keep 
all the points as well as the curve 
and a special drawing command, and so on.

---

**Edit:**

Perhaps, a closest to the MetaPost construction
would be a one-liner

```
draw(operator..(...sequence(new triple(int k){return (sin(k),cos(k),sin(k/10));},10))..cycle);
```

which combines @Charles Staats answer 
with the  `sequence()` command.

Comment: Is there a way to produce a list using a loop? say in path3[] faces={...}

Comment: @Anton Petrunin: Why not? For example, `fases.push(...);`
or `fases[k]=...;`.Check out some examples in docs or on this site, or 
u can ask a specific question for help.

Comment: I need to draw something Schwarz's boot https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lantern#/media/File:Schwarz-lantern-6-10.png If you know a similar code in asymptote, please share.

Comment: @Anton Petrunin: Gladly, just create a new question.