# How can I animate the polar graph of Trisectrix of Maclaurin?

Tags: asymptote, animations

From [my previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/579328/213378), this is my code from g.kov's answer:

```
import graph;
import math;
import animate;
settings.tex="pdflatex";

size(300);
real a=2;

animation Anim;
real f(real t){ 
  return a/2*(4*cos(t)-1/cos(t));
}

xaxis(xmin=-2,xmax=4,Ticks(Step=1,modify=NoZero,pTick=invisible));
yaxis(ymin=-3,ymax=3,Ticks(Step=1,modify=NoZero,pTick=invisible));

real dtheta=0.25;
int n=500;
guide g=polargraph(f,-pi/2+dtheta,pi/2-dtheta,n,operator ..);
draw(g,dashed);

for (int i=0; i<360; ++i){
save();
drawline((0,0),dir(i));
drawline((a,0),(a,0)+dir(3*i));
Anim.add();
restore();
}
erase();
Anim.movie(BBox(2mm,invisible));
```

The output

[image: https://i.imgur.com/Y6KDNyj.gif]

I want to get this red curve like this:

[image]

[image: https://i.imgur.com/AHwHOk2.gif]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, we already know the parameter equation of the tracing curve, so just draw it in each frame of the animation. For simplicity, the following is an animation of a point on a circle (it looks like our Earth is rotating around the Sun).

[image]

```
// save as x.asy, 
// compile with asy x.asy to get x.pdf in several pages
// then using this ImageMagick command:
// magick -density 200 x.pdf -alpha remove x.gif

import graph;
import animate;
unitsize(1cm);
real a=3;
animation Anim;
real x(real t){return a*cos(t);}
real y(real t){return a*sin(t);}

guide g=graph(x,y,0,2*pi,operator ..);
draw(g,dashed+gray+linewidth(.2pt));
fill(unitcircle,orange);

for (int i=0; i<360; i=i+2){
save();
real irad=radians(i);
guide gtracing=graph(x,y,0,irad,operator ..);
draw(gtracing,red+linewidth(1pt));
fill(circle((x(irad),y(irad)),.2),blue);
Anim.add();
restore();
}
erase();
Anim.movie(BBox(2mm,invisible));
```

**Update:** Now adapting to the situation of OP. To control the flow of animation, I construct a suitable sequence for moving angles
avoiding i=90 and i=270 where cos(i)=0.

```
int istep=2;
int[] arrangle;
for (int i=0; i<90; i=i+istep)
arrangle.push(i);
for (int i=90+dtheta; i<180; i=i+istep)
arrangle.push(i);
for (int i=180; i<270; i=i+istep)
arrangle.push(i);
for (int i=270+dtheta; i<360; i=i+istep)
arrangle.push(i);
```

[image]

The complete code

```
import math;
import graph;
import animate;
unitsize(1cm);
real a=2;
animation Anim;
real f(real t){ 
return a/2*(4*cos(t)-1/cos(t));
}

xaxis(xmin=-2.5,xmax=4.5,Ticks(Step=1,modify=NoZero,pTick=invisible));
yaxis(Ticks(Step=1,modify=NoZero,pTick=invisible));

int dtheta=2; // in degrees
int n=100;    // smooth
guide g=polargraph(f,-pi/2+radians(dtheta),pi/2-radians(dtheta),n,operator ..);
draw(g,dashed);

// spiral for moving angles
pair spiral(real t){ // t is in degree
real trad=radians(t);
real r=.1+trad/50;
return r*(cos(trad),sin(trad));};

// construct sequence for moving angles 
// avoiding i=90 and i=270 where cos(i)=0
int istep=2;
int[] arrangle;
for (int i=0; i<90; i=i+istep)
arrangle.push(i);
for (int i=90+dtheta; i<180; i=i+istep)
arrangle.push(i);
for (int i=180; i<270; i=i+istep)
arrangle.push(i);
for (int i=270+dtheta; i<360; i=i+istep)
arrangle.push(i);
 
for (int i : arrangle){
save();
real irad=radians(i);
guide gtracing=polargraph(f,0,irad,n,operator ..);
draw(gtracing,.5red+.5white+linewidth(1pt));
draw(arc((0,0),.5,0,i),blue);
drawline((0,0),dir(i));
guide stracing=graph(spiral,0,3*i,operator ..);
draw(shift(a,0)*stracing,blue);

drawline((a,0),(a,0)+dir(3*i));
fill(circle(f(irad)*dir(i),.08),red);
clip(box((-2.5,-3.5),(4.5,3.5)));
Anim.add();
restore();
}

erase();
Anim.movie(BBox(2mm,invisible));
```

**Update 2** *(update some code as OP requested)*
**Tracing animation without knowing (parameter) equation.**

Knowing (parameter) equation is just one way of determination of moving points. In case there is other way to get the position of moving points then we can connect all moving points from the beginning to the current position.

Again for simplicity, use the first example. First define an array of moving point

```
pair[] arrMovingPoints;
```

Now in the loop, after getting the moving point `tmp`, we push it in the array `arrMovingPoints`, then draw the moving curve through all points in `M` with the joining syntax `operator..(...arrMovingPoints)` (see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/494885/140722) by @Charles Staats).

```
pair tmp=a*dir(i); // the moving point
arrMovingPoints.push(tmp);
draw(operator..(...arrMovingPoints));
```

Below is the full code, there is no (parameter) equation at all.

[image]

```
import animate;
unitsize(1cm);
real a=3;
animation Anim;
pair[] arrMovingPoints;
fill(unitcircle,purple);

for (int i=0; i<360; i=i+2){
save();
pair tmp=a*dir(i); // the moving point
arrMovingPoints.push(tmp);
draw(operator..(...arrMovingPoints),pink+1);
fill(circle(tmp,.2),red);
Anim.add();
restore();
}
erase();
Anim.movie(BBox(2mm,invisible));
```

Comment: never mind! this is my comment with code and figure that I think it can be adapted to answer your question

Comment: i am a bit busy! it takes time to deal with 2 branches of red curves, and 2 green curves. On this nice forum, someone can help you for sure!

Comment: You can answer your own question. It is also helpful for others

Comment: Makes me want to learn Asymptote :)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Asymptote is rich in mathematical flavor, worth to experience!