# Tikz Animination in Circle

Tags: tikz-pgf, animations

How can I get the full circle to stay after the last frame ? Sorry I am unable to post the actual animation but it works. I just want the full circle to remain after one revolution.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\foreach \angle in {0,1,...,360}
{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2, rotate=0]

    \draw[white] (0,-2.5) -- (0,2.5);

    \draw[white] (-2.5,0) -- (2.5,0);
    
    \draw[blue,fill=blue] (0,0) circle (1.25pt);
    
    \draw[thick,blue] (0,0)--({2*cos(\angle)},{2*sin(\angle)});

    \draw[red,fill=red] ({2*cos(\angle)},{2*sin(\angle)}) circle (1.25pt);
    
    \draw (2,0) arc (0:\angle:2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You must add an image, another tikzpicture containing something like `\draw[blue] (0, 0) circle (2);` outside the `\foreach`command.  For a more precise answer, you must provide a complete code producing the animation.  Or at least an explanation.

Comment: I guess what you want is a TikZ analogy of this https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/579868/140722